# Will 30 GOTO 10 always go to 10?

Tags: compiler-optimization

In the spirit of the [latest podcast](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/podcast-53/) where Joel mentioned he'd like some simple questions with possibly interesting answers ...

In the environments we have to programme in today we can't rely on the order of execution of our langauage statements. Is that true? Should we be concerned?

Will 30 GOTO 10 always go to 10?*

*I didn't use 20 on purpose ;)

[edit] for the four people voting for closure of this question ...

"Runtime compilers use profiling information to help optimize the code being compiled. The JVM is permitted to use information specific to the execution in order to produce better code, which means that the compiling method M in one program may generate different code than compiling M in another"

(from Java concurrency in practice, 2006, Goetz et al)

.. have a look at "monomorphic call transformation"

[edit]

and another edit, your processor is allowed to swap the order of execution of statements ...

Comment: Um, which environments are those?

Comment: Well, if you look into virtual machines like th JVM, the memory model for it is allowed to swap the order of execution of statements depending on the circumstances it finds itself in

Comment: I don't know the details about the JVM, but surely it can only do that if it's already decided that there's no chance it can change the observable functionality of your code by changing the order of execution.

Comment: @Rich B: I rolled back your change. If you think this question is nonsense, there are other ways to indicate this than retagging it "nonsense".

Comment: I can't make heads or tails of the question, myself; what do you mean, will it always GOTO 10?  That's what you wrote, isn't it?  If it doesn't GOTO 10, you had better get a better BASIC interpreter.  I wish we could close questions with a reason like "question is totally unclear."

Comment: If the question is unclear, you can request more information in a comment, rather than closing it. ;)

Comment: The question becomes a lot clearer when you see how it is tagged. Compiler optimizations make a lot of transformations on your code. So "will 30 GOTO 10" still go to 10 after these optimizations?"

At least that's how I understand it

Comment: indeed jalf, maybe i was a bit obtuse

Comment: This is a valid question.  Why must moderators close questions that they're not smart enough to understand?

Comment: Control freaks? Anyway, voting to reopen

Comment: @jalf:  That seems like a really totally silly question to me.  He's basically asking, will the compiler optimize my code so that it doesn't do what I wrote?  Obviously the answer is no, your program will do what you wrote, if the compiler's working; that's its job.

Comment: It's obvious to you or me because we know the answer. Not everyone does, hence this question. There are a lot of questions on SO that I find obvious. Apparently others disagree, because the questions still get asked. And as long as people want them answered, isn't this the right place to do so? The OP discovered that compilers change your code (they do), and asks about how safe these changes are. Seems fair to me.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, it will not. But it will always **behave** as if it did. One of the basic rules in compiler design is the "as if" rule. Your compiler can make whatever changes it likes, as long as the result is going to behave *as if* you'd followed the language rules.

GOTO 10 may decide to jump to some other location, as long as the compiler can guarantee that it won't change the outcome of the program.

So no, it shouldn't worry you.

Comment: For example, if 10 GOTO 100, the compiler is likely to compile it as 30 GOTO 100.  (This doesn't often happen in hand-written code, but this sort of thing happens all the time in compiler-generated intermediate code.)

Answer (score 13):

Not if you've got

```
40 COMEFROM 30
```

somewhere in your code.

Comment: The language description specifies a certain range of ratios of "PLEASE" clauses(IIRC), lest your program seem either impolite or obsequious to the compiler.  Is it defined whether a single-line program needs a "PLEASE"?

Comment: I admit, my INTERCAL-fu is lacking. This is of course the BASIC-variation. In ITERCAL it would be "PLEASE COMEFROM .3" or something like that.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, it won't if it doesn't execute, for example if there's a `20 GOTO 40`.

Answer (score 1):

In BASIC, yes. In other languages, it will generate a compile error.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to say? Anyone claiming to be a programmer should know (especially after your hint) that it depends on what's on lines 10 and 20, and anyone who's been on SO for longer than a week should realize that this question doesn't seem to add much.

We should rely on the code doing exactly what we tell it to. If we tell it to `GOTO 10` on line 30, but also tell it to skip line 30, we shouldn't be the least surprise when line 30 is skipped. We told the program to.

Comment: You compiler is allowed to make changes to the order of execution of your statements. So is your processor. Are you aware of this?

Comment: As jalf pointed out, it doesn't matter for the results. Why bother?

Comment: Because it's a vaguely interesting question?

Answer (score 0):

True, if you consider multi-core CPUs executing a BASIC program, one of the cores might accidentally miss the GOTO (hint: "TLB Bug") and continue as if it weren't there.