# In what circumstances can a compiler change the execution order of programme statements?

Tags: compiler-optimization

If this is [not a real question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865871/will-30-goto-10-always-go-to-10-closed) then feel free to close ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler can change the execution order of statements when it sees fit for optimization purposes, and when such changes wouldn't alter the observable behavior of the code.

A very simple example -

```
int func (int value)
{
    int result = value*2;
    if (value > 10)
    {
       return result;
    }
    else
    {
       return 0;
    }
}
```

A naive compiler can generate code for this in exactly the sequence shown. First calculate "result" and return it only if the original value is larger than 10 (if it isn't, "result" would be ignored - calculated needlessly).

A sane compiler, though, would see that the calculation of "result" is only needed when "value" is larger than 10, so may easily move the calculation "value*2" inside the first braces and only do it if "value" is actually larger than 10 (needless to mention, the compiler doesn't *really* look at the C code when optimizing - it works in lower levels).

This is only a simple example. Much more complicated examples can be created. It is very possible that a C function would end up looking almost nothing like its C representation in compiled form, with aggressive enough optimizations.

Answer (score 9):

Not only the compiler can reorder execution (mostly for optimization), most modern processors do so, too. Read more about execution reordering and [memory barriers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier#Out-of-order_execution_versus_compiler_reordering_optimizations).

Answer (score 4):

Many compilers use something called "common subexpression elimination".  For example, if you had the following code:

```
for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
    x += y * i * 15;
}
```

the compiler would notice that y * 15 is *invariant* (its value doesn't change).  So it would compute y * 15, stick the result in a register and change the loop statement to "x += r0 * i".  This is kind of a contrived example, but you often see expressions like this when working with array indexes or any other base + offset type of situation.